# ClassNotFoundException using Spark library through Bazel

Tags: bazel, spark-java

I am trying to run a "hello world" server in Spark building it with Bazel, but I am getting this error:

```
$ bazel run //:app
INFO: Analysed target //:app (0 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:app up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/app.jar
  bazel-bin/app
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.201s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
        at spark.Service.<clinit>(Service.java:56)
        at spark.Spark$SingletonHolder.<clinit>(Spark.java:51)
        at spark.Spark.getInstance(Spark.java:55)
        at spark.Spark.<clinit>(Spark.java:61)
        at io.app.server.Main.main(Main.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 5 more
```

BUILD:

```
java_binary(
    name = "app",
    main_class = "io.app.server.Main",
    srcs = ["src/main/java/io/app/server/Main.java"],
    deps = [
        "@org_slf4j_slf4j_simple//jar",
        "@com_sparkjava_spark_core//jar",
    ]
)
```

The same error happens if I don't include slf4j, and it should not be a required dependency of spark.

WORKSPACE:

```
maven_jar(
    name = "com_sparkjava_spark_core",
    artifact = "com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.7.2"
)

maven_jar(
    name = "org_slf4j_slf4j_simple",
    artifact = "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.21"
)
```

And finally, src/main/java/io/app/server/Main.java:

```
package io.app.server;

import static spark.Spark.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    port(3000);
    get("/", (req, res) -> "Hello World");
  }
}
```

Any idea of what I could be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found what I was missing. It seems that maven_jar does not automatically fetch the "transitive dependencies" that the library itself has, [see this](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/external.html#transitive-dependencies).

> Bazel only reads dependencies listed in your WORKSPACE file. If your
>   project (A) depends on another project (B) which list a dependency on
>   a third project (C) in its WORKSPACE file, you'll have to add both B
>   and C to your project's WORKSPACE file. This requirement can balloon
>   the WORKSPACE file size, but hopefully limits the chances of having
>   one library include C at version 1.0 and another include C at 2.0.
>
> Large WORKSPACE files can be generated using the tool
>   generate_workspace. For details, see Generate external dependencies
>   from Maven projects.

So the solution seems to be to write a pom.xml and use [generate_workspace](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/generate-workspace.html).

EDIT: generate_workspace seems to be deprecated, use [bazel_deps](https://github.com/johnynek/bazel-deps) instead.

Comment: I edited the post to make it clear that bazel-deps is preferable over generate_workspace. There is a lot of open issues on generate_workspace repo and it does not seem to be maintained anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution might be to use maven_install

```
git_repository(
    name = "rules_jvm_external",
    commit = "22b463c485f31b240888c89d17e67c460d7e68c0",
    remote = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external.git",
)
load("@rules_jvm_external//:defs.bzl", "maven_install")
maven_install(
    artifacts = [
        "org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:3.1.2",
        "org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:3.1.2",
    ],
    repositories = [
        "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/",
    ]
)
```